# Javascript Maximum call stack size exceeded error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm working with socket.io to send and receive data from a server. I have a "Create Game" button client side that allows me to make a new GameServer on the server side. From there, I am displaying client side the information inside of game.show(). Upon clicking "Create Game", all of my console.log messages (both server and client side) are being sent, but then the server stops and gives me this error.

```
buffer.js:407
  return b instanceof Buffer;
           ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.[Symbol.hasInstance] (<anonymous>)
    at Function.isBuffer (buffer.js:407:12)
    at hasBinary (/rbd/pnpm-volume/09796244-83a8-4b11-b56a-df421860dd93/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/has-binary2/1.0.3/node_modules/has-binary2/index.js:44:66)
    at hasBinary (/rbd/pnpm-volume/09796244-83a8-4b11-b56a-df421860dd93/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/has-binary2/1.0.3/node_modules/has-binary2/index.js:58:59)
    at hasBinary (/rbd/pnpm-volume/09796244-83a8-4b11-b56a-df421860dd93/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/has-binary2/1.0.3/node_modules/has-binary2/index.js:58:59)
    at hasBinary (/rbd/pnpm-volume/09796244-83a8-4b11-b56a-df421860dd93/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/has-binary2/1.0.3/node_modules/has-binary2/index.js:58:59)
    at hasBinary (/rbd/pnpm-volume/09796244-83a8-4b11-b56a-df421860dd93/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/has-binary2/1.0.3/node_modules/has-binary2/index.js:58:59)
    at hasBinary (/rbd/pnpm-volume/09796244-83a8-4b11-b56a-df421860dd93/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/has-binary2/1.0.3/node_modules/has-binary2/index.js:58:59)
    at hasBinary (/rbd/pnpm-volume/09796244-83a8-4b11-b56a-df421860dd93/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/has-binary2/1.0.3/node_modules/has-binary2/index.js:58:59)
    at hasBinary (/rbd/pnpm-volume/09796244-83a8-4b11-b56a-df421860dd93/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/has-binary2/1.0.3/node_modules/has-binary2/index.js:58:59)
```

Here is what's run when I click the "Create Server" button

```
    if (this.add.clicked()) {
      var sid = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5);
      console.log('1');
      emitToServer('create', sid);
      console.log('2');
      emitToServer('addtoserver', sid);
      console.log('3');
      console.log('4');
      state = "GAME";
      console.log('5');
    }
```

Here is where I get the "create" and "addtoserver" messages server-side

```
    socket.on('create', function(id) {
      console.log('3');
      console.log("Creating server " + id);
      servers.set(id, new GameServer(id));
      console.log(servers);
      console.log('d');
    });

    socket.on('addtoserver', function(sid) {
      try {
        console.log('1');
        console.log('Adding socket to ' + servers.get(sid));
        servers.get(sid).addClient(socket);
        console.log('pork');
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.log('error');
      }
    });
```

Full Code: [Github](https://github.com/Shawn11564/Hidy/tree/glitch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem occurs because you are storing `socket` object in `GameServer.sockets` array and socket object is circular. When emitting that array in your `serv()` function, you are facing the problem of it trying to send the whole `socket` object, and enters recursion inside of it. Consider either not saving the whole `socket` in the array, which seems reasonable, or not to emit the whole `socket` object. If you console.log() the `socket`, you will see those circular fields.